# How do I scan a java file for only certain rule?

Tags: sonarqube

I exclude our JUnit test from the scanning, however, I would like for it to be scanned for certain set of rule, how can I configure SonarQube to do this?

Comment: Note: cross-posted on mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sonarqube/Aby5We2KETc/lUNMxxNMBgAJ

Answer (score 1):

The SonarQube documentation page [Narrowing the focus](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus) allows you to specifically target some files for given set of rules. It probably can help you achieve what you want to do.

Now, the SonarJava analyzer already separates *Main* sources files from *Test* Source files. Correctly configured, your project will then apply only rules targeting tests on files categorized as "Test Sources". The same way, rules are usually targeting Main sources only.